Trying to replace label text to underscore for a game of hangman
So I'm trying to learn a bit of Python and see how far I can progress. So my nephews said why not make a small game of hangman. And I thought, why not.
So far after following a few tutorials and reading a ton, I have it (finally) that the first page has an input and it has a button that let's it go to the second page where it'll show the word that is inputted on the previous page, with another 2 buttons, one is not working, the other is to change the word (so going back to the first page).
What I'm trying now is to change the word that shows on the second page (the one you have to guess) to underscores. So if the word is "Hello" I would like it to be _ _ _ _ _ . So far this is where I'm stuck and even after following some stuff, I can't figure it out.
Also still need to figure out how to still see the word as valid when it's written like "Banana" or "banana" (doesn't matter if it has uppercase or not etc).
This is the code so far. Thanks in advance for any advice.
class Galgje(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.shared_data = {
            "gekozenWoord": tk.StringVar()
        }

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=500,  weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=600, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (KiesMain, GekozenMain):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("KiesMain")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.grid()

class KiesMain(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Kies je woord")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady="10")
        self.woordEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"])
        self.woordEntry.pack(pady=10)

        btnContinue = tk.Button(self, text="Ga verder", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("GekozenMain"))
        btnContinue.pack()


class GekozenMain(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Raad het woord!")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        def underscoreWoord(woordLabel):
            ' '.join('_' if c in woordLabel.ascii_letters else c for c in woordLabel)

        woordLabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"], font=("futura"))
        woordLabel.pack(side="top")


        self.wentry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.wentry.pack(pady=10)
        RaadButton = tk.Button(self, text="Gok!", command=self.RaadWoord)
        RaadButton.pack()
        NieuwWoord = tk.Button(self, text="Ander Woord", command=self.AnderWoord)
        NieuwWoord.pack()

    def RaadWoord(self):
        return True
        
    def AnderWoord(self):
        self.refresh()
        self.controller.show_frame("KiesMain")

    def refresh(self):
        self.wentry.delete(0, "end")
        #self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.wentry.focus_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    galgbord= Galgje()
    galgbord.mainloop()

What I did try and see if I could get it to work as creating a function for converting it with .split but couldn't figure it out completely.

Hopefully this answers your two questions. To get around the matching case issue, just put everything into lower case. And for the other, just count the number of letters in the word, and generate that many dashes or underscores:
supplied_word = "Banana"

# To get around the case problem, put everything into lower case
supplied_word_lc = supplied_word.lower()
print(supplied_word_lc)

# Generate dashes for the word
dashed_word = "-" * len(supplied_word)
print(dashed_word)

This prints:
banana
------

By the way, I have used dashes here rather than undrscores because dashes show up in the font used here (underscores are harder to count as they merge into each other).

This would actually seem to work, but I have no idea where to put it.  Since I need to loewr the controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"] but they are all in tk.Label or in tk.Entry. Tried putting .lower() after the entry and after the label and such, but then it doesn't recognize either .lower() or it doesn't recognize .pack()

If you have a tk.Label object named label you can extract the string from it with label_string = label.cget("text"), and then you can use the code I posted. If you have a tk.Entry object named entry, you can extract the string from it with entry_string = entry.get(), and you can then use the string with the code I posted.

If my answer answers your original question, could you please accept it so that others know that the question has been answered.

Sorry haven't had much time past few days to check in on this. Sorry. For the code, I am still struggling a bit to get it right with .cget and stuff. So the line where the 'word' is, is: woordLabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"], font=("futura")).
Now I did try to add this: loweredWord = label.cget(Woordlabel), I tried loweredWord = label.cget("gekozenWoord") and I also tried loweredWord = woordLabel.cget("gekozenWoord"). But they all draw an error:
"Can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str.

Can you supply a minimal example of your code which shows up the issue that you have.  It may be best to do this in a separate question (and ideally also close off this one by accepting the answer).

The whole code I am using is above. That's the whole code :) .

I thought the code was incomplete because there were no imports, but I have added a tkinter import and the code appears to be complete. But although I understood your original question and answered it, I do not understand what you want next. I think the only way to clarify things is for you to ask a new question. Say (again) clearly exactly what you are trying to do, and say what you have tried, and what goes wrong. Also it would help very much if the instructions could be in English so we can see how it is supposed to work.

Hmm yes I will go ahead and do that. And yes I see now I was missing my import, or atleast forgot to include it in the post. But yes you did answer the question so I will mark it as solved and answer a new one. With english terms instead of Dutch ones.
Thanks so far in advance and I will try and be more clear on what I want to happen. Thanks though!

Thanks very much. I think that is a good way forward.
